# Can we find a specific word in a docx file using python?

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, python-docx, word-frequency

I have tried using the python-docx module. So far, I have been able to extract specific paragraphs and also the whole text out of the word file.

`pip install --pre python-docx  #to install python-docx`

```py
from docx import Document
document = Document('file.docx')

document.paragraphs  # to extract paragraphs
document.paragraphs[2].text  # gives the text
​
for par in document.paragraphs:  # to extract the whole text
  print(par.text)


# I tried the below code to find some specific term
for i in range(0, 50, 1):
  if (document.paragraphs[i].text == ('Some-word')):
    print document.paragraph
```

I expect to find a specific word in a highlighted form in a word file

Comment: use `'Some-word' in document.paragraphs[i].text`

Comment: I tried using it. There is no output for either of them.

Answer (score 1):

It would search through all paragraphs

```
for par in document.paragraphs:  # to extract the whole text
  if 'Some-word' in par.text:
     print(par.text)
```

Comment: How can we copy some "sentences" after the specific word we found using this method?